# Minimising Chrome Or Changing Tab Pauses HTML5 Game

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have noticed something that happens only in Google Chrome when testing my HTML 5 slot games. When I minimise Chrome or even change to a different tab, it "pauses" my game.

So for example, I will set it up to do 10 spins, then minimise the window. I can wait 5, 10, 15 minutes and it won't start playing until I maximise the window again.

I checked in Firefox, and the game plays in the background when minimised. Searching for this issue has come up with nothing at all, does anyone know a way to fix this? It's super weird.

Thanks!
Heather

Comment: Which method are you using for the game "loop" ? `setTimeout` ? `setInterval` ? `requestAnimationFrame` ?

Comment: I am using GreenSock's TweenMax to run an animation, do you think the issue is in that then?

Comment: I'm not sure how TweenMax works, but if it's running requestAnimationFrame under the hood, then is what will happen. But don't worry, this is normal, and good behaviour! It prevents laptop/mobile batteries from being drained unnecessarily if a CPU intensive operation like animation is minimized or in a non-visible tab.

Comment: Yeah I think it is using requestAnimationFrame, I guess that must be it then thanks!